# Make Chart TextAnnotation Appear Behind DataPoints

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mschart

Is there a way to add a TextAnnotation to a Chart control in C# where the annotation appears behind the datapoints?  There doesn't seem to be a way to send the annotation to the back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did u try to change the Z-Order of the text annotation in PrePaint event

Check this Link
http://support2.dundas.com/OnlineDocumentation/WebChart2005/Annotations.html

Search for "Working With Z-Order"

Comment: I tried this code, but I got an Error at myRectAnnotation.Paint(chrOI, e.ChartGraphics); because Paint is inaccessible due to it's protection level. Do you know of any other links / tutorials that explain how to change the z-order?

Comment: The link provided in this answer is for `Dundas Charts` where the question is taged with `mschart`.

Answer (score 0):

My dirty solution for use in a Point Chart. Redraw every datapoint on top of everything else.

```
Private Sub Chart1_Paint(chart1 As Chart, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Chart1.Paint
    For Each chartSeries As Series In chart1.Series
        Dim ca As ChartArea = chart1.ChartAreas(chartSeries.ChartArea)
        For Each chartPoint As DataPoint In chartSeries.Points

            'Determine the position, size and color of the original datapoint.
            Dim x As Double = ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(chartPoint.XValue)
            Dim y As Double = ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(chartPoint.YValues.First)
            Dim b As New SolidBrush(chartSeries.Color)
            Dim width As Double = chartPoint.MarkerSize
            Dim r As New Rectangle(x - width / 2, y - width / 2, width, width)

            'Draw the new datapoint on top of the original (and on top of any annotations)
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(b, r)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```